# Android how to make GET or POST Http Request using url with an IP address instead of HostName

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Hi all I am trying to send data to my development database from android application using Post but am getting exception

```
09-18 15:23:36.801: W/System.err(6755): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.255.162.84:8080/web/events
09-18 15:23:36.801: W/System.err(6755):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
```

If I copy paste the url the web browser in my computer. the webpage I am trying to get works.
If I replace the url with `https:www.google.com` in my application, it works.
What does this mean? I can't connect make http connection without a host name?

code

```
URL url = new URL("http://10.255.162.84:8080/web/events");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(20000 /*millis*/);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /*millis*/);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.connect();

                System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
                char[] buffer = new char[500];
                reader.read(buffer);
                System.out.println(new String(buffer));
```

Additional information

The server to receive get and post requests is running on my PC port 8080 via a broadband connection. 
I am running the application on my low end phone running android 2.2 (Froyo)
I hope that's all the relevant information but am glad to provide more. I know you get this all the time but **I swear to you I am really new to android**

Comment: no need to specify port number http://10.255.162.84/web/events write like this and try

Comment: @BirajZalavadia Removing the port form the Url didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your android device is not on the same network as your computer. You can test this easily by pasting the url into an android browser and checking to see if it works. Your server is most likely behind your network's firewall. You'll need to configure [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) to allow external clients to connect.

Comment: I am able to connect to the server through the url in my app using the phones browser or opera mini. But when I try it through the app I get HttpResponseCode 500 (file not found). So I don't think port forwarding is my problem because the server is receiving requests from external connections. Any other suggestions?

Comment: A 500 is a server error, not a file not found. I would use a web proxy like fiddler to examine differences between requests. Perhaps the server does some sort of inspection on user agents, I don't know. See this for setting up Fiddler: http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid